# Garlic Rasam as exception to Aryuvedic Rule

Tags: food, gunas, ayurveda

So I know in many cases garlic and other pungent foods/spices lead to high Rajistic tendencies due to a highly concentrated amount of emotion. But, I also heard sattvic food is any good food that purifies the body and many make garlic rasam a warm soup that has high medicinal properties. So, does the way you cook it also matter for certain non-meat ingredients? Any scriptural proof for such would be good in responding to this answer.

Comment: Well, Āyurveda even considers certain types of meats to have medicinal properties. A food may have medicinal properties and may help in the treatment of some specific diseases/ailments, but that doesn't imply it's sāttvika. Laśuna (garlic) is recognized to have medicinal properties in Āyurveda surely.